# How can I keep a single component highlighted at a time in Elm 0.17?

Tags: elm

I have a game UI with a variety of components, some of which can be clicked on to become highlighted (the 'active' component). That is currently done by having a Bool in the state of each component that can be highlighted. However, I'd like to enforce that only one component can be highlighted at once - so, if something is clicked on, whatever else is currently highlighted has to update to un-highlight.

One way to do this is to have the common ancestor broadcast some message down to all of the various children, and every component can handle this message and turn itself off - however this seems pretty complicated and wasteful. There could be 1000 components, and only two are changing (one to highlight and one to un-highlight), so why should I send out and handle 1000 messages?

Is there a better way?

note: this seems pretty similar to [Elm 0.17: How to subscribe to sibling/nested component changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328203/elm-0-17-how-to-subscribe-to-sibling-nested-component-changes). I think that one difference is that in that question there's a small number of related components, and when one changes the other always changes. In my case there are many many components at various locations in the overall model, and when one changes few or none of the others will change.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there probably is a better way. Duplicating some state in multiple places of an app is not recommended because it leads to synchronization problems and makes debugging harder.

Instead you would be better off not storing the highlighted state in the components but only in the main model. Then the components' view function would take an additional boolean "highlighted" parameter.

To store the highlighted state in the main model, you could give an ID to each component and add `highlighted : Maybe ID` to the model.

Thus, you will only have to propagate the click message from children to parent but not from parent to children.

Answer (score 1):

The Elm runtime and the virtual DOM engine will ensure that only the components that changed will be re-rendered. So I wouldn't worry too much about sending messages to 1,000 components.

In your case:

- your update function would change only 2 components to set/ unset the active state/ only send out messages to 2 components.
- your view function would always run for all 1000 component's
- Elm's virtual DOM diff engine will only render the 2 components that changed to the DOM.

When working with components with internal state, what you would need is:

- each component needs to know whether it is active or not. Probably a `Bool`.
  Could be a field in the component's `model`.
- the global `model` needs to know which of the components is active. Possibly with a `Maybe Int`, where `Int` is the ID of the active component.
- when a component is clicked to make itself active, it will send some `Msg` to the parent which should include its ID, so parent knows which component is now active. (see an [example here](https://github.com/debois/elm-parts/blob/master/examples/2-counter-list.elm) of how this could work)
- the parent's `update` function updates the active element in its own `model` whenever it gets a message element. And parent updates 1 or 2 child components to change the active flag of those components.